# Add C++ support to Eclipse for Java

Tags: c++, eclipse

So, I am in my first year of programming classes and have been struggling with all of the different programs I have to use to code. My java professor has asked us to use Eclipse and I really like it a lot. My C professor had us download Visual Studio at the beginning of the year which I have on my desktop. However, I just bought a Mac and now I'm stuck using Xcode as well (which admittedly I really love). I was hoping to consolidate all of my programming into Eclipse on all my machines. I currently have the Java version of it installed.

Could someone give me a quick how-to on adding C++ support to the program and hopefully a list of desirable settings. When I try to do it myself, programs fail upon build displaying errors like "Binaries do not exist." Thank you in advance!

Comment: Help->Install New Software->All Available Sites->CDT Main Features->CDT Development Tools (May also want to choose from CDT Optional Features)